# Browser Caching using IIS8.5, am I doing it right?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I have applied the rules below to my web.config ;

```
 <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/less" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <remove name="Vary"></remove>
      <add name="Vary" value="Accept-Encoding" />
      <add name="Cache-Control" value="public" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

```
<caching>
   <profiles>
     <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="5.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".png" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="5.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="5.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".ico" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="30.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".woff2" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="5.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".woff" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="5.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".ttf" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="5.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".js" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="2.00:00:00" />
     <add extension=".css" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="2.00:00:00" />
  </profiles>
</caching>
```

The thing is, when I check the response, I am having this output `Cache-Control no-cache,max-age=864000`. Does no-cache means the browser is not caching it?

Here is an example output

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   no-cache,max-age=864000,public
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  249
Content-Type    text/css
Date    Mon, 16 Mar 2015 07:37:29 GMT
Etag    "872ee528715ed01:0"
Last-Modified   Sat, 14 Mar 2015 16:08:50 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You did it right and your page is caching well.

You can refer to the explanation of [Cache-Control MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control). the Cache-Control header value **no-cache** means caches must check with the origin server for validation before using the cached copy.
 Your cache going to be revalidated on every **864000** seconds.It might revalidate the content using the `If-Match` or `If-None-Match` headers with an `ETag`, or it might use the `If-Modified-Since` or `If-Unmodified-Since` headers with a date. Here is the directives explanation from MDN,

> **max-age**=`<seconds>`
>   The maximum amount of time a resource is considered fresh. Unlike Expires, this directive is relative to the time of the request.
>
> **no-cache**
>   Caches must check with the origin server for validation before using the cached copy.

Comment: Thanks! So what is the exact difference between `policy` and `kernelCachePolicy`? And what exactly does kernelCachePolicy do?

Comment: The kernelCachePolicy is used to control caching in http.sys and policy is used to to control caching in w3wp.exe, consider the Microsoft IIS architectures for more information on pros and cons https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture